# How to resolve Android Studio's error in reading the XML files in building/compilation?

Tags: java, android

I've created a new Android Studio project, and while it was Building the project it gave me the following error:

C: Users, Asus, Desktop, Dionisio, App, Src, Main res, Colors.xml: 1: 1: Error: Content is not allowed in the prologue.

And when I opened that XML file it was all corrupt.
I tried to create other projects and it still gave me that error.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you provide more details, and the xml file here .

Comment: Here's how the XML looks like:
�PNG   IHDR   �   �   R�l  :�IDATx��]XTGמ]`A)v���b/`7Fc�]EŮ���EE�Ui����]c�Qc�i�'�)_̗�b��(,�ϙ{/�]��ݽ�,zo��`�en���yϙ3�"$�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�aҁ� %$�ё j        �Y���i[�!VrZߒ��#GЊ}����

Comment: try Invalidate Caches/Restart once ..

Comment: I've already done it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this reinstalling Android Studio.